# Appending span with certain class name JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to append a span with some certain class name. I am using a JavaScript **MAP** to get the class name. So that it can append the appropriate class name.
I am able to get the value using:
 `mymap.get(value.status)` but I am but I not able to pass as class name with span like:

`<span class...`

```
function refresh() {
    var $table = $("table#mytable");

    $.getJSON("//127.0.0.1:8001/get_latest_verification", function (obj) {

        $.each(obj, function (key, value) {

            var mymap = new Map();
            mymap.set('Registered', 'badge badge-info');
            mymap.set('Tampered', 'badge badge-important');
            mymap.set('Verified', 'badge badge-success');
            mymap.set('Void', 'badge badge-inverse');
            mymap.set('Released', 'badge badge-inverse');

            var state = mymap.get(value.status)

            var rows = "";

            rows = rows + "<tr>" + "<td>" + value.asset_code + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.scan_time + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.credential + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<span class='state'>" + value.status + "</span>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.operator + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.location + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.auth_code + "</td>" + "<td>" + value.emp_id + "</td>" + "</tr>";

            $table.prepend(rows);
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: _" I am using a javascript MAP"_ - What's a JavaScript Map? Why wouldn't you use an ordinary JS object for that purpose (and why do you recreate the map on every iteration of the `.each()`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use string concatenation to add the class attribute value since `state` is a variable holding the class name

```
"<span class='" + state + "'>"
```

instead if `"<span class='state'>"` which creates a span with class `state`